# Deploying Prism app as both WPF and Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, prism

Is it possible to develop a Prism 4 app and then use it both as a WPF app and a Silverlight app?

If not what is involved in converting it from WPF to silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's one of prism goals. Take a look at article '[Building WPF and Silverlight Applications with a Single Code Base Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321573.aspx) Prism'